# Где ошибка в коде. На первом else пишет invalid sintax

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
print("Загадайте в уме число от 1 до 5", end = ' ')
 input("и нажмите Enter")
a = input("Ваше число больше 3-х? Отвечай только Да или Нет.")
if a == 'Да':
a = input("Ваше число 4?")
if a == 'Нет':
    с=5
    else:
        c=4
    else:
        a = input("Ваше число 1?")

        if a == 'Нет':
            с=1
            else:
           a = input("Ваше число 2?")
    if a == 'Нет':
                с=3
                else:
                    c=2
print("Я угадал! Ваше число", с)
```

Comment: Как минимум отступы неверные

Comment: Если пишет "invalid sintax", то надо очевидно надо править синтаксис. В питоне отступы имеют значение.

Comment: if (условие):  
   <код>  
else if(другое условие):  
   <код>  
else if(еще одно условие):  
   <код>  
else:  
   <еще немного кода>.  
Без условного блока может быть только один блок else. Если требуется несколько блоков else, ставьте после них еще оператор if в виде else if(условие): <код>

Answer (score 4):

Во-первых, не может два `else` следовать друг за другом. Во-вторых, в коде проблемы с отступом.

Помимо неправильно расставленных отступов имеется и логическая ошибка в следующем фрагменте

```
    a = input("Ваше число 1?")

    if a == 'Нет':
        с=1
```

Должно быть

```
    a = input("Ваше число 1?")

    if a == 'Да':
        с=1
```

Предложения if-else могут быть расставлены следующим образом

```
print("Загадайте в уме число от 1 до 5", end = ' ')
input("и нажмите Enter")

a = input("Ваше число больше 3-х? Отвечай только Да или Нет.")
c = 0

if a == 'Да':
    a = input("Ваше число 4?")
    if a == 'Нет':
        c=5
    else:
        c=4
else:
    a = input("Ваше число 1?")
    if a == 'Да':
        с=1
    else:
        a = input("Ваше число 2?")
        if a == 'Нет':
            с=3
        else:
            c=2
print("Я угадал! Ваше число", с)
```

Comment: А как переписать код чтобы не было проблемы

Comment: @Rewr Erer Нужно взять книгу про Python и прочитать про  if-else предложение и правильно использовать отступы.